# How to control Videolan VLC through HTTP JSON requests?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vlc

I am trying to build a web application to control a VLC media player.
Once enabled the web interface, I can successfully submit requests with Postman. Instead in my app, using jQuery to make AJAX calls, the XMLHttpRequest fails with a 501 during preflight.

This is the simple AJAX call i make:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url:     'http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.json',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "password")
    },
})
```

This is the answer:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.

VLC's internal server does not support CORS or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `VLC's internal server does not support CORS` it sounds like that may well be the case. If so you can't do this through JS

Comment: Thank you very much. it looks a strange thing to me nowadays to implement a JSON interface and not enabling CORS requests…

Comment: Update as a reference for other readers, at the moment there is an open issue on Videolan's trak:
[Add CORS headers to the HTTP interface](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/8848)